# Uso de vetores e busca binária em portugol

Tags: array, portugol, busca-binária

Uma das atividades mais usadas no computador é localizar um objeto (número ou cadeia de caracteres) em um conjunto de dados.
Você deverá desenvolver um algoritmo que permita encontrar um número em um vetor de 100 números sequenciais de 1 a 100.

Requisitos:
Os números deverão ser gerados e armazenados em um vetor no momento da execução.

O algoritmo de busca a ser implementado é o de busca binária.

O usuário deverá entrar com o número que deseja verificar se está no vetor.

O sistema deve criticar se o usuário digitou número entre 1 e 100.

Caso ele tenha digitado números fora desse intervalo o sistema deverá informar que só aceita números de 1 a 100.
Informa quantas comparações foram necessárias para localizar o número.

Para essa questão fiz o seguinte algoritmo:

```
principal


// Declarações

    inteiro num[100];
    inteiro valorDig, meio, fim, inicio;
    logico continuar, encontrou;
    fim = 100;
    inicio = 1;
    encontrou = falso;


    // Instruções
    escreva("Digite o desejado: ");
    leia(valorDig);
    enquanto (inicio<=fim e nao encontrou) faca
        meio = (fim + inicio)/ 2;
        se (num[meio] == valorDig) entao
            encontrou = verdadeiro;
        fimSe
        se (num[meio] > valorDig) entao
            fim = meio - 1;
        senao
            inicio = meio + 1;

        fimSe
    fimEnquanto



fimPrincipal
```

Não obtive sucesso, queria ajuda para saber o que posso consertar ou mesmo se alguém teria uma melhor solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eae cara, o algoritmo de busca parece certo mas tem algumas coisas que vc pode arrumar:

1: preencher o vetor com os valores de 1 a 100

2: inserir mais um se(if) pra saber se o início é maior ou igual ao fim, neste caso vc teria que sair do enquanto porque a busca terminou, dá pra usar uma interrupção (break) pra fazer isso.

3: Vc deveria guardar o resultado da busca(se encontrou ou não o número procurado).

Boa sorte aí espero ter ajudado